# Deployment: Separating the library jars from my own classes

Tags: tomcat, deployment, war, ear

I was wondering if there is a way to put all the needed .jars in a separate .war/ear so that when I made a minor change in my code I don't have to deploy all the library .jars to the server?

Because uploading 50mb (to an offside Tomcat server) every time I want to test a change/during development is not a great way to spend your time.

Most topic I read on SO stated that you do want a self containing .war file. In this case it is only shared with 1 .war file. Not sure if this is possible with some kind of library reference in the deployment descriptor.

Comment: Have you tried to put these jars into the servlet container's class path (this possibly has negative consequences for other webapps, but it probably solves your upload problem)? JBoss 7 provides a solution for this using its modular class loading concept.

Comment: No I haven't but I will explore that option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Java EE Spec](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html), your .jars are supposed to be deployed to `WEB-INF/lib` within your WAR file. I have seen some folks hack the Tomcat classloader to pull from an external directly (especially after Tomcat 5+ removed support for `CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib`), but that has its obvious downsides.

I'd suggest looking at changing your deployment process instead of changing the code. You can actually do an "exploded WAR" deployment to `appBase` (see [Tomcat docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying%20on%20a%20running%20Tomcat%20server)), and only transfer the files that have changed.

I work for [Inedo](http://inedo.com/), and I've seen a lot of users do this with [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster). The workflow looks something like this:

1. Get Latest from $/MyApp
2. Run Ant (build.xml)
3. Unzip MyApp.war
4. Create Build Artifact
5. Stop Tomcat Service
6. Deploy Build Artifact to SERVER (/path/appBase)
7. Start Tomcat Service

The last step (Deploy Build Artifact) will only deploy the files that changed, which will greatly reduce the time it takes to deploy your 50MB artifact.